# Different Kind of physical memory representation?

Tags: eclipse, memory-address, disassembly

I'm very new to "low level" programming and actually I'm just stepping through some code within eclipse. In the "Disassembly view" within eclipse, the first column represents the memory address. It looks like:

```
000936fc:   E5DCC000 LDRB            R12, [R12]
00093700:   E35C0000 CMP             R12, #0
```

So, the "dummy"question:
I know only the representation of memory like in this way:

```
0x5600000:

0x825ffff:
```

So, is the memory address of the first example, the same like the following one? :

```
0x0936fc
0x093700
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple interpretations of your question. The simplest is "Why are these addresses shorter". The answer is they are 0 extended to the program counter word length.

Another possible question is why these addresses are different, while I'm not familiar with Eclipse's debug menu, so I'm going to make some assumptions about where you are deriving those numbers from. Provided Eclipse gives information similar to other debuggers, you are simply viewing the handiwork of a linker.

These addresses are broadly known as virtual address and are the consequence of [relocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)), which may be imposed for a host of reasons too numerous to enumerate.